# How to deal with java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class called communicator. This class is a listener of a thread receiving events from another program. Also this class has a method call refresh that sends and action to the program a waits for the response that comes through the listener.

Both methods are in the same class but called by diferent threads.

```
public void processRefreshEvent(ManagerEvent event){
    //processing event
    //...
    //I'm done
    notify();
}


public synchronized void refresh() throws Exception {
    isRefreshing = true;    
    try {
                    manager.send(new refresh());
    } catch (ManagerException e) {
        isRefreshing = false;
    }

    try {
            wait(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } finally{
        isRefreshing = false;
    }
}
```

when executing the code above I get the follow exception:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread not owner
>         at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>         at Communicator.refresh(Communicator.java:203)
>         ...
> ```

What is the proper way to "wait" for another thread to finish. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to synchronize your threads on a monitor. For instance (using the current object as the monitor):

```
public void processRefreshEvent(ManagerEvent event){
        //processing event
        //...
        //I'm done
    synchronized(this) {
        notify(); // you are basically notifying any thread who has blocked
                  // on this monitor - in our case, the instance of this object
    }
}


public synchronized void refresh() throws Exception {
        isRefreshing = true;    
        try {
                    manager.send(new refresh());
        } catch (ManagerException e) {
                isRefreshing = false;
        }

        try {
          synchronized(this) {
                wait(5000); // wait will give up the monitor
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } finally{
                isRefreshing = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, "any thread" means "any ONE of the waiting threads" not "all waiting threads".

Comment: Also note that the waiting thread may wake up of its own accord.

Answer (score 1):

The methods [`wait()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [`notify()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) may only be called from a thread that is currently synchronized on their instance.

Declare "processRefreshEvent" `synchronized`, or better yet, just the block of code that modifies the state that is used by the `refresh` method, together with the `notify()` call.

```
public void processRefreshEvent(ManagerEvent event){
  // processing event
  synchronized (this) {
    // modify shared state with results of processing.
    notify();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to wait until another thread has finished? Then just call join() on the Thread object you want to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

From `Object.wait()`'s JavaDocs:
"The current thread must own this object's monitor."
So you need to synchronize on the object that you're invoking wait on.

Alternatively you could use `BlockingQueue`, which implements `Collection` and `Queue`.  `BlockingQueue` does all the work of wait and notify. Your thread can just call `take()`, which will block until data is available. You add data to the queue using the various insert methods (add, put, etc). BTW the insert methods call `notify` while `take()` calls `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the JavaDoc on [java.lang.Object.wait()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [notify()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()).

You should synchronize the wait() with the proper monitor, in this case:

```
try{
    synchronized(this){
          wait(5000);
    }
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
} finally{
            isRefreshing = false;
}
```